# How to make same HTML section open in one div and close in another div

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML using Jquery

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordian/jquery-1.9.1.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
   $(".Topping-details").hide();
  var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
   $("#ordersdiv").prepend(divdata);
  });


 </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div  class="activateUiHTML"  data-role="collapsible">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
      <form><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="59" > 
         <label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Ice Cream Butter Scotch</label> 
      </form>
      <div class="Topping-details" id="59">
         <section id="topping_tsection_59">
            <i id="topping-close"></i>
            <aside>
               <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
            </aside>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div id="ordersdiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

When clicked on the CheckBox , i have a listener in which i am appending data to the div called **ordersdiv**

I am struck at one place .

When i click on the checkbox ,  i want to hide the html present inside **Topping-details** class when it is added to the **ordersdiv** and it must **not** be closed under **activateUiHTML** div

Right now when i used `$(".Topping-details").hide();` it is being hiding in both the div's .

could anybody please help me how to reslve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/1/)**

You need a different selector to hide `.Topping-details` inside `#ordersdiv`

Use `$("#ordersdiv .Topping-details").hide();` after you append the html.

Try this,

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {


    var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();


    $("#ordersdiv").prepend(divdata);
    $("#ordersdiv .Topping-details").hide();

});
```

**Note :**

Your html append is generating duplicated ID checkboxes.

Comment: Note that you've also changed the binding so that any matching `.checkboxclas` elements added to the DOM after this runs won't invoke this handler.  The OP may have been using `.on()` for a reason.

Comment: Ohh Thank you for pointing that out, I just noticed `id="59"` in OPs markup

Comment: Good catch on the duplicate `id`s in the OP's code, I hadn't noticed that.  But I still recommend not changing the binding selector like this.  Why not use the same delegated binding that the OP was using?  Was there a reason you changed it?

Comment: Oops, sorry again, I was just copying the code from my fiddle. Delegation is most important in this case. Silly mistakes

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only want to hide the "Topping-details" `div`s which are children of the "ordersdiv" `div`?  If so, you can simply use both of those in the selector:

```
$("#ordersdiv .Topping-details").hide();
```

This will hide only the elements with class "Topping-details" *only if* they are also child elements of the "ordersdiv" element.